# Is It Possible to Add Cross-Field Async Validation In Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I am trying to add an asynchronous validation to form level (for cross-field validation). But the validation function is not getting triggered. Is it Possible to add Async Validation in Form Level? Or what is wrong with my validation?

// my form

```
creatForm(): void {
    this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
      firstName: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(15)]],
      lastName: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(15)]],
      phone: [null,
        [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10), Validators.maxLength(10)],
        [this.phoneValidity.checkPhoneValidity()]],
      email: [null,
        [Validators.required, Validators.email],
        [this.emailValidity.checkEmailValidity()]],
      password: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(15)]],
      rePassword: [null, [Validators.required]]
    }, { /*validators: [PasswordRePasswordValidator],*/ asyncValidators: [PasswordRePasswordValidator]});
  }
```

//my validator

```
export function PasswordRePasswordValidator(control: FormGroup): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
    const password = control.get('password').value;
    const rePassword = control.get('rePassword').value;

    console.log('password', password);
    console.log(rePassword);

    let v: Observable<ValidationErrors | null>;

    return v = new Observable(observer => {

        if (password && rePassword) {
            console.log('password exists');
            if (password === rePassword) {
                observer.next(null);
                observer.complete();
            } else {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    observer.next({unMatchPassword : 'Password Doesn\'t Match'});
                    observer.complete();
                }, 1500);
            }
        } else {
            console.log('password isnt exists')
            observer.next(null);
            observer.complete();
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Why do this? Are just trying to make this more complicated than it needs to be? I can see making this asynchronous if you were making a trip to a server for validation, but you aren't. KISS: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-cross-validation-to-reactive-forms

Comment: I am validating password and re-password fields to see if they match or not. I am sending setTimeout() to give user a little time before the error kicks in and it feels conventional thing to do. To use setTimeout i need to send either promise or observable.

There are other ways of course but I thought it is the right way. And anyway, I wanted to know whether it is possible to add asyncvalidators in form level or not

Answer (score 1):

In order to validate password and confirm password u can just use small trick. Set pattern for confirm password input with password value. Then its automatically validates .

```html
<input formControlName=“password” />  
<input formControlName=“confirmPassword” [pattern]=“form.get(‘password’).value” />
```